# Unable to install google-drive-ocamlfuse on Fedora 38

Tags: fedora, mount, dnf, google-drive

I would like to mount Google drive to a local directory and for that, I would like to install `google-drive-ocamlfuse` on my up-to-date Fedora 38 but I get the following errors:

```
$ sudo dnf install google-drive-ocamlfuse
Last metadata expiration check: 0:21:15 ago on Sun 29 Oct 2023 09:59:45 AM.
Error: 
 Problem: package google-drive-ocamlfuse-0.7.22-3.fc33.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse requires ocaml-ocamlfuse > 2.7.1, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides ocaml(CamlinternalFormatBasics) = b6c6694955e10001aed267571104a961 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Com) = 26b1234e7a6d75ba1450cb5357f5483c needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Condition) = 76cd8b455eb0162ced68da0cd9930f3a needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Mutex) = ec993c9491bec46cd3ee373f9d313390 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Stdlib) = 4b04b4eda19aa722df365141895fb347 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Stdlib__bigarray) = 73871e61e3785d8f0d822194daeb85ec needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Stdlib__callback) = 21c02abb4cc9eea752b0e9ab3b1a0e6a needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Stdlib__complex) = 81367aaa1be1ccaf16610a96c3d2bc13 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Stdlib__either) = 2555bf09b020b8887a4d8a645b0ed347 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Stdlib__hashtbl) = c3ec10b93bb358686d02fa9c5f4adb6b needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Stdlib__list) = 88609ef3a3066dcf16ad7456f53122d2 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Stdlib__seq) = 185075aa99b059ad4cae15cb411fcc0c needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Stdlib__string) = 9f0e42299fccc5fb76df62d28ba67759 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Thread) = a5f19c00abf12e43bcffa2998c478777 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocaml(Unix) = eadecc353e942963afccd09bd1a12192 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocamlx(Condition) = 2f0a4dd0f67fcd0ce2134d45cebebdc6 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocamlx(Mutex) = 9e92b5f80ce643a8259210bbb7a4e1e3 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocamlx(Stdlib) = 905355729c82ef4d2184c394a250f1a3 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocamlx(Stdlib__callback) = f51ffea73ea6512880e00974c161a04c needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocamlx(Stdlib__hashtbl) = d6c11956a20f699b6d99ffbeaf7af8ce needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocamlx(Stdlib__list) = 53d7956dcffc648bb93ed4703fe49f2c needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocamlx(Thread) = 5b8312fda8f617d11b90ef0b5611e3d9 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
  - nothing provides ocamlx(Unix) = 6cad08ee79360aa0781ccb2644c36087 needed by ocaml-ocamlfuse-2.7.2-0.3.git08f90ac.fc35.x86_64 from copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:jgoguen:google-drive-ocamlfuse
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Can anybody help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install google-drive-ocamlfuse you need to enable sergiomb repo:

```
sudo dnf copr enable sergiomb/google-drive-ocamlfuse
sudo dnf install google-drive-ocamlfuse
```